# gstreamer webrtcbin audio and video can not play simultaneously

Tags: webrtc, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

```
#define STUN_SERVER " stun-server=stun://stun.l.google.com:19302 "
#define AUDIO_CAPS  "audio/x-mulaw,media=audio,channels=1,rate=8000"
#define RTP_CAPS_PCMU "application/x-rtp,media=audio,encoding-name=PCMU,payload=0"
#define VIDEO_CAPS "application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,payload=97,encoding-name=H264"

gst_parse_launch("webrtcbin bundle-policy=max-bundle name=sendrecv "  STUN_SERVER
                    "appsrc name=audio_src is-live=true format=time ! " AUDIO_CAPS " ! rtppcmupay ! queue ! " RTP_CAPS_PCMU " ! sendrecv. "
                    //"audiotestsrc is-live=true wave=red-noise ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue ! mulawenc ! rtppcmupay ! " RTP_CAPS_PCMU " ! sendrecv. "                        
                    "appsrc name=video_src is-live=true format=time ! " VIDEO_CAPS " ! rtpjitterbuffer ! queue ! " VIDEO_CAPS  " ! sendrecv. "
                    //"videotestsrc is-live=true pattern=ball ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! queue ! " VIDEO_CAPS  " ! sendrecv. "
```

1.`audio_src` and `video_src` independent, audio and video is ok.

2.`audiotestsrc` and `videotestsrc` simultaneously, audio and video is ok.

3.`audio_src` and `videotestsrc` simultaneously,  ok .

4.`audio_src` and `video_src` at the same time , **chrome no audio.**

5.`audiotestsrc` and `video_src` at the same time, **chrome no audio.**

if link `audio_src` to `webrtc` first, no video, but audio is ok.

Give some hints, tks!